# TypeError: list objects are unhashable

Tags: python

```
totalCost = problem.getCostOfActions(self.actions)
```

Comment: You posted so much information that I'm still processing it. I think it will take a day or two to process such a big amount of details.

Comment: Common! we are not supposed to guess. Please post some code.

Comment: it is executed by running multiple files....cant put up the whole code here

Comment: I'm with pakore, I'm overwhelmed by the enormous quantity of material given in the question.

Comment: M making a project....search IN pacman....so it is using multiple files

Comment: @Shilpa, publish the smallest amount of code which still produces the problem. How do you expect us to help if you are not giving us the information needed to help? We are not mind readers you know.

Comment: I know...i think it might be a common error that you all know.

Comment: Cut him some slack, it **is** a common error.

Comment: @Shilpa - above that error message you posted there would be a stack trace, which shows you the file where the error originated. Often an error will go through several "callers" before it makes your program die, but if you look carefully, the stack trace almost always gives you enough information to find out what's causing the problem, or at least **where** it's starting. The interesting lines start with `File "something.py", line XX, in ...`, and the bottom-most is where the error started. The lines above that is the function which called *that* one, and so on.

Comment: @Shilpa: What Python tutorial are you learning from?  Please provide the name or a link.

Comment: @matt: What it has to do with anything? OP was given an answer within 2 minutes! If he wants anything more useful, he need to put more efforts into the question.

Comment: The relevant code would be the function `getCostOfActions` and the initialization of `self.actions`.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you are trying to use a list as key in a dictionary or something like that. Lists are not hashable, and so they cannot be used as dictionary keys or in sets.

On another note, python gives you a stacktrace when such an error happens, and that includes file-names and line-numbers. You should be able to track down the offending code with that.

**Edit** About stacktraces:

```
cat > script.py
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = {}
bar[foo] = "Boom"
print "Never happens"

python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module> // this is the file and the line-number
   bar[foo] = "Boom"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: can be plz tell me how to use stacktrace? where is it ? what commands I need for it?

Comment: @Shilpa: where did you copy the error message from? there were many more lines there, copy the whole lot.

Comment: @Shilpa: The stack track is what prints when your program crashes.  No commands.  It's what you see.

Comment: +1 for not being a jerk. You might mention that if you *have* to use a sequence for a `dict` key or `set` element, a tuple works.

Comment: File "pacman.py", line 616, in ?


   runGames( **args )        

  File "pacman.py", line 584, in runGames game.run()

  File "", line 482, in run

    agent.registerInitialState(self.state.deepCopy())

  File "/game.py", line 292, in directionToVector

    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]

TypeError: list objects are unhashable

Comment: @Shilpa - post it in your question (you can edit questions!) and remember to mark it as code.

Comment: @Shilpa: Please **UPDATE** your question with these facts.  Do NOT post import information in comments.  Please UPDATE your question.

Comment: @Shilpa: Now your  question makes no sense at all.  None.  Zero.

Comment: Ya..i just edited my question...i dont need help in this question now..so i just deleted my code from here....

Comment: @Shilpa: Do you get how this site works?  Other people have the same problem as you.  A useless, unreadable code sample is not a question that will help others.  You've made this question useless with your edit.

Answer (score 6):

You've probably attempted to use mutable objects such as lists, as the key for a dictionary, or as a member of a set. Mutable items cannot be tracked for such uses efficiently and predictably so they do not provide the hash special attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The error is produced when an unhashable type is added to sets.

```
>>> s=set((1,2))
>>> a.add([3,4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I think this may be also your case. Use tuple instead of list:

```
>> a.add((3,4))
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the line should be like this instead

```
totalCost = sum(map(problem.getCostOfActions,self.actions))
```

or if you prefer a generator expression

```
totalCost = sum(problem.getCostOfActions(action) for action in self.actions)
```

Since I can't see your code, I assumed that `problem.getCostOfActions()` returns the cost of a single action, as that might cause the error you are getting if `self.actions` is a list

Alternatively you could fix the function `problem.getCostOfActions()` so that it returns the total cost of a list of actions as the name suggests.

Consider adding the body of this function to your question if you want help fixing it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with django :
food_list = ['spam' , 'more spam' , 'spam spam']
table.cum.add(food_list)

and I got error - TypeError: list objects are unhashable.

The fix is table.cum.add(*food_list)
-add * infront of list to unpack it
the model method add accepts args - (x,y,z) but not ([x,y,z])

hope it helps